# What are the chances of a -7 Question being Reopened?

Tags: discussion

After making a [total hash of a first time question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678348/slickquiz-in-asp-net-mvc-5), the OP now has a -7 score on his/her first question, and was quite rightly closed as 'unclear'. After some coaxing, the question has been formatted and sufficient information now exists to assist the OP in solving same.

I am however of the opinion that the question won't survive the reopen queue given, given the bias against its score. Is there a way forward for the OP on this question?

Comment: 3 votes already, so it has a chance.,, 4 now

Comment: Is the real question here "can people please go and vote to reopen it"? If you wanted an answer to the title question then you could have just waited and seen.

Comment: I'm actually just curious as to the mechanism here. If OP deletes and reposts, am guessing he risks other penalties. And no, I'm not trying to feather a Red Baron hat :)

Comment: It is reopened now.

Comment: Your advertisement put it back on the path to getting reopened.  Whether you *actually* did anybody a favor is fairly doubtful.  Him arbitrarily switching to another JS framework, posting a wall of code and making the question [tags] invalid surely won't make this a candidate for a lasting Q+A pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would it deserve to be reopened, or as of now, stay open? It's literally *"I need this JSON, I have this Knockout that should generate it, but it generates this JSON"*, so I do not agree with your *"sufficient information now exists to assist the OP"*. It's unclear, too broad and off-topic.

Comment: Well, the question is again at 3 close votes, so the tribe has spoken. First time posts are like a box of chocolates :)